# Использование библиотеки Otto

Tags: android, otto

У меня есть два activity: mainActivity & secondActivity.

Мне нужно, чтобы по событию в mainActivity, выполнился код из secondActivity.

Нужно ли мне запускать secondActivity для того, чтобы там выполнился код?

Как сейчас делаю:

В mainActivity:

```
BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);

BusProvider.getInstance().post(new Event());
```

В secondActivity:

```
BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);

@Subscribe
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        //этого никогда не происходит
        Toast.makeText(this, "Event handled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: А есть не тоаст а так: `System.out.println("Я вызван из второй активити по событию!");`? А вообще активити вторая должна быть при этом хотя бы раз запущена. Т.е. перейдя со второй на первую код может выполниться, а если вторая не запускалась или была прибита системой, то оно не выполнится. Так что лучше как-то вообще не так делать. Напишите чего вы хотите добиться всем этим.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо, Вы ответили("если вторая не запускалась или была прибита системой, то оно не выполнится") на мой вопрос ) Напишите ответ.

Comment: Если не отписываться в активити от получения событий то будут возникать утечки памяти. Вообще никогда не должно быть ситуаций, когда в одной активити нужно вызывать код другой активити. Если такая ситуация возникает, то либо что-то не так с вашей архитектурой, либо этот код можно вынести в отдельный класс и использовать его. Так что я бы советовал пересмотреть вашу архитектуру.

Comment: @temq, спасибо за дельный совет. Правда, я в onStop() делал unregister:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вторая активити должна быть хотя бы раз запущена. Т.е. перейдя со второй на первую код может выполниться, а если вторая не запускалась или была прибита системой, то код не выполнится.